# What is up with Python 3.4 and reading this simple XML site?

Tags: python, xml, wireshark

I have a device that has a simple web server that has a page with XML. I would like to capture the results with Python 3.4. The site looks exactly like this as taken from the source code for the page.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datavalues>
<units>F</units>
<sensor1temp>67.5</sensor1temp>
<sensor2temp>57.9</sensor2temp>
<sensor3temp>54.6</sensor3temp>
<sensor4temp>x.x</sensor4temp>
<relay1state>0</relay1state>
<relay2state>0</relay2state>
</datavalues>
```

The code I'm using is super simple as shown here:

```
import urllib.request
url_str = 'http://192.168.1.2/state.xml'
f = urllib.request.urlopen(url_str).read()
print (f)
```

I get an exception that looks like this:

```
http.client.BadStatusLine: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

I Wiresharked the response. The data came back in four blocks Frame11/Ethernet II/Internet Protocol Version 4/TCP. The data for the xml was contained in the Frame 11 portion. Not too sure what that means.

I use Jython 2.5 at work and the above technique works just fine. Is there a Python 3.4 solution available? Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Oh my. That server is replying with HTTP/0.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that server is replying with the data directly without providing a status code, as HTTP/0.9 did. Apparently `urllib.request` doesn’t support that. Fortunately HTTP/0.9 is a simple protocol, so it should be easy enough to do with plain sockets:

```
import socket
from io import BytesIO

conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
conn.connect(('192.168.1.2', 80))
conn.send(b'GET /state.xml\r\n')
buffer = BytesIO()
while True:
    chunk = conn.recv(4096)
    if chunk:
        buffer.write(chunk)
    else:
        break
data = buffer.getvalue()
```